# pyspark column value is a list

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

Working with a dataframe which contains a column, the values in the columns are lists, how could I process such column

```
id    |   values
1     |   [1,1,2,4,3,5,6]
2     |   [1,2,3,5,6,7,8]
....
```

For each row take the first three values and get the max out the first three

Expected as:

```
id  | max_value
1   | 2
2   | 3
....
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [slice](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#slice) and [array_max](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#array_max) functions from pyspark `sql.functions`

For example, by passing `array_max(slice(values, 1, 3))` to `F.expr`, you are first list(`slice`) and taking max (`array_max`)

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
df
.withColumn("max_value", F.expr("array_max(slice(values, 1, 3))"))
.show(truncate=False)

+----------------+-
|id |max_value|
+----------------+-
|1  |2      |
|2  |3      |

+----------------+-
```